# Comparing Hashed Password in the database to user Input in PHP MYSQLI

Tags: php, mysqli, crypt

How do I compare hashed passwords  that are stored in the database to a user inputted password, I need to do thsi so that the user could log in.

Here's how I hashed my password (using phps crypt method)

```
$hashedpass = crypt($password);
            $sql = "INSERT INTO accounts (username,password,email) VALUES('{$username}','{$hashedpass}','{$email}')";
            $conn->query($sql);
```

This is how  I compare them to user input

```
$username = trim($_POST['username']);
        $password = crypt($_POST['password']);
        $sql = "SELECT * FROM accounts WHERE username = '{$username}'  &&  password = '{$password }'LIMIT 1";
        echo "$sql";
        $rs = $conn->query($sql);
        $numRows = $rs->num_rows;
        if($numRows == 1){
            echo "you may log in";
        }
```

I am 100% sure that I enterd the password correctly but the thing is mysql is not showing results,

Comment: '{$username}' should be '$username' right?

Comment: What difference would it make? but either way, you're correct

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at the [PHP documentation](http://php.net/manual/en/function.crypt.php) for crypt, as you are not supplying a SALT value you will get strage results often ending up with the hash of one value not matching with another hash of the same value.